# Json array converted to formdata becomes string

Tags: json, reactjs, express, multipartform-data, form-data

From react app I am converting Json into Form data but when I receive data on the server end

the arrays and objects that I sent become strings

```
var formdata = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
     formdata.append('Images', images[i], images[i].name)
}

formdata.append('City', State.city)
formdata.append('Description', State.description)
formdata.append('Things_to_Pack', JSON.stringify(thingsToPack))
formdata.append('AreaContacts', JSON.stringify(Contacts))

axios.post(`${url}/city/create`, formdata, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        }).then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        });
```

The data received on the server

```
City: 'City Name',
Description: 'Description of city',
Things_to_Pack: "["bag","clothes"]"
AreaContacts: "[{"title":"Emergency","contact":"1111"},{"title":"Emergency","contact":"2222"}]"
```

Expected Output should be

```
City: 'City Name',
Description: 'Description of city',
Things_to_Pack: ["bag","clothes"]
AreaContacts: [{"title":"Emergency","contact":"1111"},{"title":"Emergency","contact":"2222"}]
```

How can I change it into proper Json form before saving in database ? I have also tried json.stringify the req.body data but it didn't work

```
//Post City at this route 
router.post('/create', upload.array('Images', 12), async (req, res) => {
    let imagesArray = [];
    if (req.files) {
        for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
            imagesArray.push(req.files[i].path)
        }
    }
    console.log(req.body, req.files);
    const city = new City({
        City: req.body.City,
        Description: req.body.Description,
        Images: imagesArray,
        Things_to_Pack: req.body.Things_to_Pack,
        AreaContacts: req.body.AreaContacts
    });
```

Comment: json is a string notation. Those strings you have are in fact proper JSON form. If you want to convert them back into objects/arrays, you should JSON.parse them.

Answer (score 1):

```js
Things_to_Pack: JSON.parse(req.body.Things_to_Pack)
AreaContacts: JSON.parse(req.body.AreaContacts)
```